# Как убрать оповещение о выключении через 10 минут

Tags: windows, windows-10

В консоли Windows я прописываю команду

```
shutdown -s -t 3600
```

Она выключает компьютер ровно через час, но за 10 минут до выключения выдаёт вот такое уведомление, которое будет висеть по середине экрана пока его не закрыть.

[image]

Существует ли какой нибудь флаг в команде shutdown, чтобы это уведомление не высвечивалось?

Comment: Вероятно, [**здесь**](https://superuser.com/a/559755/572069) ответ на Ваш вопрос. Спасибо.

Comment: `shutdown -a` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодаря [этой статье](https://superuser.com/questions/559736/avoid-system-will-shut-down-in-10-minutes-using-shutdown-on-windows/559755#559755) я решил свою проблему следующим образом:

1)Создал несколько .bat файлов со следующим содержанием:

```
timeout -t 1800 -nobreak && shutdown -s -t 00
```

где 1800 - количество секунд через которое будет выключен компьютер.

2) Назвал их shut10.bat, shut30.bat, shut60.bat, shut120.bat, shut240.bat,
где после shut пишется количество минут через которое выключится компьютер.

3) Переместил эти файлы в папку system32
[image]

4) Нажимаю Win+R и в "Выполнить" пишу "shutXX"